# How do I Include the TraceOutputOptions in the output of Enterprise Library Logging

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, callstack, enterprise-library-5

This is wrecking my head and the documentation seems to be non-existent for this library.
I have a Rolling Flat file listener... I want to include the callstack in any messages that get written to the listener.

```
 <add name="RollingFileLog"
           fileName="C:\Rainmaker\Logs\SampleArchitectureService.Log"
           ... snipped for brevity
           traceOutputOptions="Callstack" />
```

What do I need to include in my Formatter to get that Callstack/Trace info to appear. Formatter is below

```
<add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, ..."
           name="TextFormatter"
           template="{timestamp(local)}: [{category}/{severity}] - {message} - ****WHATGOES HERE***" />
```

I've tried everything, looking in the extended properties dictionary, using the {property()} and {keyvalue()} tokens for which there is no documentation either.

Can someone please explain to me wht this `traceOutputOptions` attribute is for, and if it's for what I think, how the heck do I access those attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trace Output Options from the MSDN page

The TraceOutputOptions property determines the optional content of trace output. The property can be set in the configuration file or programmatically during execution to include additional data specifically for a section of code. For example, you can set the TraceOutputOptions property for the console trace listener to TraceOptions.Callstack to add call stack information to the trace output.

Also remember it's not supported by all the trace listeners
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.traceoutputoptions.aspx

The only way I see to get the CallStack information into your file is through the extended properties dictionary in the text formatter.

```
template="Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
```

Found an interesting article, this should help you. "How to output TraceOutputOptions values "
http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/344343

Comment: Note for others with issues: if using the config file to set the output options, the traceOutputOptions setting in the file is case sensitive and must have an initial lower case 't' as it does in this sentence.